# shinyDirButton versus fileInput in Docker

Tags: r, docker, shiny

I'm building a Shiny app in Docker and ran into a weird buttons behavior. When I use `shinyDirButton` (from ShinyFiles package) to access the file system (I need the user to select an output folder for their analysis), it works fine and I see files inside Docker.

However, when I use simple `fileInput` to select a file, the button opens the window showing me my file system, on my computer, not inside the Docker. I'm very curious what's going on here and how I could fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FileInput runs in the browser and shows you client (not the shiny server)

Maybe you want to use shinyFilesButton instead, if you want to select a file from the server.

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/shinyFiles/versions/0.3.2/topics/shinyFilesButton

Comment: Thank you! It was not obvious for me that FileInput is using my client. Now the problem is fixed with shinyFilesButton, great

Comment: is there any possibility to have the shinyFilesButton works on the browser and not on server?